# Image filters using ColorMatrixColorFilter

Tags: java, android

I am wanting to make sure that I am going down the right path with regards to image filters on Android.

I am using a color matrix and testing to get a filter that I like. Here is a filter I am using for a faded looked.

```
float[] colorMatrix = {
    .66f, .33f, .33f, 0, 0, //red
    .33f, .66f, .33f, 0, 0, //green
    .33f, .33f, .66f, 0, 0, //blue
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0    //alpha
};

ColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
iv.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

I am wanting to get a collection of filters like Instagram. My question is is this the way that I should be creating image filters or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hints:

- What you seem do here is called [color transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management), very similar to transformation of euclidean vectors. Both are used in science and computer graphics (shaders). Such a step could well be the final stage named 'color correction' of a more complex image processor.
- To make things more interesting, read about [kernels (convolution matrices)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29), which additionally involve neighbour pixels, for example to blur an image, or to enhance contours for a 'comic effect'.
- Think simple: All these topics gather under [image processing, a form of signal processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_processing). Whether you process 2D or 3D images, a mono (1D) audio stream or data from an A/D converter, the basics remain; floats don't have colors.